# How to set timezone of HSQLDB?

Tags: java, hibernate, timezone, jodatime, hsqldb

How do I set the timezone to UTC in a HSQL database?

According to the documentation [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sessions-chapt.html) one should just write:

```
SET TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE;
```

but that does not work for me.

I use HSQLDB (v2.2.8) as a memory database in combination with hibernate (v4.2.2) for unittesting and JodaTime (v2.3) for time-related data. 
Some data is inserted with SQL-scripts via `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`. These scripts use the `now()` function for creating a timestamp.

However when I retrieve the inserted value from the database and convert it to UTC I get the following results:

Without any SQL-Command like the one above:
`2014-06-04T16:44:45.193Z`
This is my current localtime, but in UTC.

With the above SQL-Command: (Note the 1 hour difference)
`2014-06-04T15:50:56.688Z`
This would be localtime if we would not have daylight savings time here.

Something that might be interesting: It does not matter what offset I provide in the above command, the output will always be the same.

**Edit:**

A sample line of my insert script:

`INSERT INTO public.users 
(created_at, modified_at, email, firstname, lastname, password, state, image_id) 
VALUES 
(now(), now(), 'max.mustermann@example.com', 'Max', 'Mustermann', 'password_hash', 'ACTIVE', NULL);`

My user entity inherits from the following entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractTrackedEntity extends AbstractEntity {
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
DateTime createdAt;

@Column(name = "modified_at")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
DateTime modifiedAt;

public DateTime getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}

public void setCreatedAt(DateTime createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}

public DateTime getModifiedAt() {
    return modifiedAt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}

public void setModifiedAt(DateTime modifiedAt) {
    this.modifiedAt = modifiedAt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    modifiedAt = createdAt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    modifiedAt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AbstractTrackedEntity{" +
            "createdAt=" + createdAt +
            ", modifiedAt=" + modifiedAt +
            '}';
}
}
```

Please note that in my particular problem, only the getters are relevant because the data is NOT inserted by hand (e.g. creating an entity and persisting with hibernate) but with the above mentioned SQL-script.

**Summarized problem:**
The database does not store timezone information with the actual timestamp value. Therefore if now() returns localtime, localtime will be inserted into the database.

Because our production database runs with timezone UTC, the code is written to treat every timestamp from the database as UTC. (Therefore those `withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)` everywhere).
In my unittests I need to compare UTC-timestamps generated in the code with timestamps from the database. These unittests break atm because a timestamp from the database, treated as UTC, is 2 hours off from the timestamp generated by the code, although they were generated just seconds apart.

Comment: Consider storing the value in UTC to begin.  Conversions can be done on the way in, and on the way out.  Also note that when showing a `Z` in an ISO8601 string, that always means UTC.  So perhaps you could show the code where you are doing the conversion and we could help there.

Comment: I know that a trailing Z means UTC. That is fine because I converted the value to UTC after reading from the database. 
I actually WANT to store the value as UTC, but calling now() in the insert script, inserts it in my localtime and because no timezone information is stored with the actual value, I get a wrong result, if I treat the value in the database as UTC. I will add some code for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [these docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_current_datetime), perhaps `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would work better than `NOW`.  I don't currently have ability to test this, but you might give it a try.

Since it returns `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, then you might also consider:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '0:00'
```

[See also this discussion thread.](http://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/thread/5a47d79e)

Comment: I get the same results if I replace `NOW` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
However, adding `AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '0:00' HOUR TO MINUTE` did the trick. Thanks!  
I am now using the following:
`now() AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '0:00' HOUR TO MINUTE`